Discrepancy in PySpark Query Results Compared to SQL Query on Open-Source Dataset
I am encountering an issue with a PySpark query that I'm running on an open-source dataset located at "/databricks-datasets/learning-spark-v2/sf-fire/sf-fire-calls.csv".
The query aims to retrieve records from the year 2018 and order them by the 'Delay' column in descending order. However, the results from the PySpark query differ from the equivalent SQL query executed on the same dataset.
Here is the PySpark query I'm using:
san_francisco_worst_response_time = fire_df.where(year(to_date(col('CallDate'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')) == 2018) \
                                            .select('Neighborhood', 'Delay') \
                                            .orderBy('Delay', ascending=False)

display(san_francisco_worst_response_time)

Pyspark Output:
| Neighborhood          | Score   |
|-----------------------|---------|
| West of Twin Peaks    | 754.08  |
| Mission               | 745.93  |
| Chinatown             | 734.87  |
| Bayview Hunters Point | 715.77  |
| Bayview Hunters Point | 714.73  |
| Bayview Hunters Point | 713.05  |
| Bayview Hunters Point | 700.00  |


The equivalent SQL query is:
SELECT Neighborhood, Delay FROM demo_db.fire_service_calls_tbl
WHERE YEAR(TO_DATE(CallDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")) = 2018
ORDER BY Delay DESC;

SQL Output:
| Neighborhood                     | Score        |
|----------------------------------|--------------|
| Lincoln Park                     | 99.68333333  |
| South of Market                  | 98.86666667  |
| South of Market                  | 98.6         |
| South of Market                  | 98.45        |
| Glen Park                        | 98.01666667  |
| Glen Park                        | 97.98333333  |
| Financial District/South Beach   | 97.78333333  |


As you can see, there is a clear difference between the PySpark and SQL query results. The SQL query returns 'Delay' values ranging from approximately 6.783 to 99.68, whereas the PySpark query returns significantly higher 'Delay' values, ranging from 9.23 to 754.08.
The SQL query is the correct one while the PySpark query yields different results.
Any insights or suggestions on potential causes or debugging steps would be greatly appreciated.

The discrepancy between the PySpark and SQL query results could be due to the date format in your PySpark query. In your PySpark query, you’re using ‘yyyy-mm-dd’ as the date format. However, ‘mm’ represents minutes in the SimpleDateFormat class, not months. This could be causing the discrepancy in the results.
Try replacing ‘mm’ with ‘MM’ in your PySpark query, like so:
san_francisco_worst_response_time = fire_df.where(year(to_date(col('CallDate'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) == 2018) \
                                        .select('Neighborhood', 'Delay') \
                                        .orderBy('Delay', ascending=False)

display(san_francisco_worst_response_time)

Hi Agam,
Thank you for your suggestion. I updated the date format in my PySpark query from 'yyyy-mm-dd' to 'yyyy-MM-dd' as you recommended. However, I am still encountering the same issue where the results differ from the SQL query.

san_francisco_worst_response_time = sf_df.where(year(to_date(col('Call Date'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')) == 2018) \                                             .select('Neighborhood', 'Delay') \                                             .orderBy('Delay', ascending=False)
Give this a try and let me know if that works. I had a detailed look and the default date format for Call Date is stored as 'MM/dd/yyyy' not yyyy/MM/dd which was the reason for the inconsistent results. (it's separated by / not -(hyphen).

Hi Agam, I tried changing the format as MM/dd/yyyy but still am getting the same output as previous.
